# Shortest route along multiple points

Tags: shortest-path

I have been trying to solve the following puzzle:
[Image of paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSbwa.png)

You have straight canals where can only move only in the direction of the green arrows and the circular canals in which you can move in both directions. The distance between two circular canals equals 4. The distance between two straight canals is 3 in the first circular canal, 6 in the second and 9 in the third. You start in the black square in the middle, you have to pass all the red triangles and return in the black square. What is the shortest route to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your current attempt at this problem? 
For general guidelines on asking questions, please refer to [ask].

Comment: I have already found a path with a length of 80. (N is movement in norhtern direction, NW means to the northwest etc. A means clockwise via ciruclar canal, B means anti-clockwise via circular canal) E B SW  W W W A A A SW A A NE A A NW. But there should be a shorter route.